# Filtering required words from a log file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a log like this.

```
cat log.log | grep 'count\|dagName'

2018-03-20T15:53:24,001 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-70([])]: 
exec.Task (TezTask.java:build(355)) - Dag name: select count(*) from 
reportingperiod(Stage-1) 2018-03-20T15:53:24,369 INFO  [HiveServer2 
Background-Pool: Thread-70([])]: client.TezClient  
(TezClient.java:submitDAGSession(522)) - Submitting dag to TezSession, 
sessionName=HIVE-8216b875-c18e-4fcb-b25c-7fd6cb8efe10, 
applicationId=application_1521559442968_0003, dagName=select count(*) from 
repo(Stage-1), callerContext={ context=HIVE, 
callerType=HIVE_QUERY_ID, callerId=hive_20180320155311_aae27431-a30d-4022-
950c-c5ddb340098c }
```

I want to select the value from the above log like this.

I want to store the extracted word into variable.like this

```
a=select count(*) from repo
```

I tried the command like this

```
a=$(awk 'BEGIN{ print "" }
 /dagName\(=/{ sub(/.*count=[^[:space:]]+: /,""); q=$0 }
 /dagName:\/\//{ print "," q }' OFS=',' log.log)
```

but the above command prints ',' only. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You `want to select the particular value` based on what criteria? If you expect us to figure out what you want by reading a script that doesn't do what you want then YMMV...

Comment: just I need to filter the expected word. I need to filter the value which starts with select count(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -oE 'select count\(.\) from [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*' log.log
```

To assign it to a variable:

```
result="$(grep -oE 'select count\(.\) from [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*' log.log)"
```

Comment: yeah it is fine, but the table name will change. It is not constant.The repo will change if any other table query is executed.

Comment: Then remove the table name from the search string.

Comment: No lets say I have a variable a=select count(*) from repo          I dont need the remaining values. I need to extract only the particular words.